# Woman gains an alien racial conscious, transforms into a feline alien

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a book that I read in my local library back in the 1990s. The cover had a picture of a face that showed a human half on the left side and a feline-like face on the right side.  The eye had definite cat-like pupils.

Three human space explorers landed or crash landed on an alien planet.  One of the explorers, a woman, came across a dying alien creature, who reached out to her and transferred his whole racial consciousness (his and his ancestors) to her.  She travels to where the whole community lives, learning to navigate a long, high narrow bridge to get there.  Once there she learns about their culture and history, and begins to transform into one of them.

Meanwhile the other two explorers "discover" the alien race and try to hunt them down.  She tries to get them to stop.  One of the explorers, a guy, ends up touching her and taking her family away from her, leaving her yearning for that family.  Eventually she kills him to get her family back, completes her transformation and returns to her new home.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).